Bash script -c option behavior
I have the following bash script: abc.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo First Arg:  $0
echo Second Arg: $1
a=$(ls)
echo Directory contents: $a

And I invoke the below command:
/usr/bin/bash -c 'source "$0" && exec "$@" ' /home/usr/rob/abc.sh   /home/usr/rob/abc.sh  ARG1

As per the documentation, with -c option, commands are read from the given string; and if we have anything outside the string, the first arg is passed to $0.
So above source "$0" will become: source /home/usr/rob/abc.sh.
So the expected output would be:
First Arg: /home/usr/rob/abc.sh
Second Arg:  
Directory contents: abc.txt abc.sh                  <-- The dir has only these two files
First Arg: /home/usr/rob/abc.sh
Second Arg: ARG1
Directory contents: abc.txt abc.sh

But what actually gets printed is:
First Arg: /home/usr/rob/abc.sh
Second Arg: /home/usr/rob/abc.sh
Directory contents: abc.txt abc.sh
First Arg: /home/usr/rob/abc.sh
Second Arg: ARG1
Directory contents: abc.txt abc.sh

The question is: when I print $0 and $1, how the first command (source /home/usr/rob/abc.sh) prints the name of the script? for both echo statements'
Ideally, it should print blank for $1; because we dont pass anything as argument.
As the same time the exec $@ prints the values (for $0 and $1) as expected.

You are assuming that source foo will cause foo to run without arguments. This is not the case.
Here's help source:

If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when filename is executed.  Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.

Since the source command has no further arguments, the positional parameters are unchanged, so $1 is still /home/usr/rob/abc.sh

From the Bash Manual description of -c:

If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.

So $1 is set to /home/usr/rob/abc.sh and $2 is set to ARG1, and $@ contains both of those.

Thanks Barmar. I have a question in this.. so for the second command which is exec, will it not get the first parm then? ( only ABC.sh and ARG1 are passed to exec)

Right. $@ contains the positional arguments, which doesn't incluide $0.
